# Help with the Bethe-Bloch formula?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, solid-state-physics, radiation

I need some help with the Bethe-Bloch formula for the energy loss of a heavy charged particle in a solid. I'm trying to write a short paper on the detection of alpha particles with a Si detector and when it comes to using the aforementioned formula I get stuck. The formula suggested by my professor is:

$$ -\frac{dE}{dx}=D\frac{Z}{A}\rho z^2 \Phi(\beta)(1+v) $$

with $$\Phi(\beta)=\frac{1}{\beta^2}\left(\log\left(\frac{2m_ec^2\gamma^2\beta^2}{I\left(1+\frac{\gamma m_e}{M}\right)}-\beta^2-\frac{\delta}{2}-\frac{C}{Z}\right)\right)$$ and $$D=4\pi r_e^2m_ec^2N_A=0.30707~\rm \frac{MeV~cm^2}{mol}$$

Here are the problems I encounter:

- I made the calculations for *D* and my result is way different, just looking at the orders of magnitude (we're using cgs units) it seems clear to me, but then again, I might be doing something wrong;
- My professor suggests that *I* is the ionisation potential, but other sources tell that *I* is the mean excitation energy, which should be greater. I'm temporarily using the latter and the "wrong" value for *D* to test the waters and the formula seems to be working fairly well (the order of magnitude is the same as the experimental data, yay!), but now my doubt revolves around the huge difference that lies between ionisation and excitation energy, can anybody help me with that? Should I use the former or the latter?

I also tried using the Bethe relativistic formula found in "Principles of Radiation Interaction in Matter and Detection" by Leroy and Rancoita but it yields absurd results. I think I'm getting something wrong with the cgs units.

$$ -\frac{dE}{dx} = \frac{4\pi n z^2 e^4}{mv^2}\left\{\ln\left[\frac{2mv^2}{I(1-\beta^2)}\right]-\beta^2\right\}$$
Thank you in advance for your precious help.